# How to declare properties file per package in struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to configure struts.xml file per package and also properties file per package. But I am unable to find out any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If by "property files" you mean resources, put a `package.properties` file in each package.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html

A `struts.xml`-per-package doesn't make any sense. You can have an arbitrary number of S2 config files, broken up by any mechanism you want, and include them in the default `struts.xml`.